# Scroll a web page with a ShieldUI chart

Tags: asp.net, charts, scroll, shieldui

I have a web page with several content including  one or more charts. When I’m on a phone or a tablet, the charts take all the place of the screen. I can’t scroll more my screen. Even if the tooltip and zoom mode aren’t activated. How desactive the scroll on the chart so that the native scroll of the page isn’t overloaded ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the zIndex property for the series settings.
This is demonstrated in the following sample:
    jsbin.com/dexuqez/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Could you please paste the relevant code that you are linking to in a Stack Snippet here?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found is to disable all events on the div:

```
div[id^="chart"] > .shield-container {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

I'm not really satisfied. This also disables popups and series selection.